# Notice: Undefined Offset php

Tags: php, notice

I have this **php** code which throws the alert `notice: undefined offset`

```
$thisMonth=$_POST['month']; //the value is today's date's month
$thisYear=$_POST['year']; //the value is today's date's year
$thisDay=$_POST['day']; //the value is today's date's day

$table=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `kids` WHERE `debt`!='0'") or die(mysql_error());
$debt=0;

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($table)){
    $explodedDate=explode('/',$row['enrollmentdate']);
    $theYear=$explodedDate[0];
    $theMonth=$explodedDate[1]; //this line throws the error
    $theDay=$explodedDate[2]; //and also this line
    if((int)$theYear==(int)$thisYear && (int)$theMonth==(int)$thisMonth){
        if((int)$theDay==(int)$thisDay || (int)$thisDay==0){
            $debt+=$row['debt'];
            }
        }
    }
```

I have been reading all over the internet for a solution but seems like this error is dependent on the code and unfortunately I can't seem to figure out how to fix it.

any ideas how to fix the error or what's causing it?

**this is the full error:**

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\kids_house\php\functions.php on line 600
>   Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\wamp\www\kids_house\php\functions.php on line 601

Comment: If you `var_dump($explodedDate)` what does it return?

Comment: @chris85 added the full error to the question

Comment: Okay thanks. So what is `$row['enrollmentdate']`?

Comment: it returns an array `2015,6,10`

Comment: @chris85 that's a field in a database that keeps the date of enrollment

Comment: @chris85 after the `explode()` it returns those numbers in an array, not as an string before calling the `explode()` function

Comment: Is it returning multiple rows of MySQL data? One of those rows may not have a date, so `explode("/", ...)` wouldn't return an array, and thus element 1 wouldn't exist (at least I think that's how it would work)

Comment: @AminJafari you are doing wrong if you are using exploding `2015,6,10` with `/`

Comment: Guys, read the following comments: *after the explode() it returns those numbers in an **array***

Comment: why are you storing dates as strings anyways? most of that loop is useless busy work because you didn't store a date properly, e.g. a real datetime field.

Comment: Read that comment wrong. Yes, `1`, and `2` won't be present if there are no `/`s. You could do a hacky solution `$theMonth=!empty($explodedDate[1]) ? $explodedDate[1] : '';`. Then the variables will just be empty. You should probably figure out why the date isn't there though..

Comment: @MarcB because I use two types of dates (Jalali or persian date and Gregorian date) so it's kinda easier to manipulate the dates if they're strings

Comment: @TimLewis interesting, I'll check on that and let you know

Comment: Yeah, if one of the rows didn't have a date, you'd be trying to this: `explode("/", "")` or worse `explode("/", NULL)`, neither of which would return an element beyond 0 (or would just flat error out). Also, look into either `date()` or `DateTime()` php classes.

Comment: @TimLewis you were correct, one row of the table didn't have any value for the `enrollmentdate` filled, fixed the bug, and now everything works as expected, you should write your comment as an answer so I can mark it as **the answer**

Comment: Glad you got it working! I'll hold off on posting an answer, as I only really found the problem, and not necessarily a good solution to fix that problem. @Fraser 's answer is a good one to go with though. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that these two lines are throwing errors is because the value in this is not yyyy/mm/dd, as you expect:

```
$explodedDate=explode('/',$row['enrollmentdate']);
```

If you look at the value that throws the error with something like this, you should see the issue:

```
$thisMonth=$_POST['month']; //the value is today's date's month
$thisYear=$_POST['year']; //the value is today's date's year
$thisDay=$_POST['day']; //the value is today's date's day

$table=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `kids` WHERE `debt`!='0'") or die(mysql_error());
$debt=0;

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($table)){
    $explodedDate=explode('/',$row['enrollmentdate']);

    if ( count( $explodedDate ) <= 1 ) {
        var_dump( $row );   //this will show you the row that is causing the notice
        var_dump( $explodedDate );   //this will show you the date
        die();
    }

    $theYear=$explodedDate[0];
    $theMonth=$explodedDate[1]; //this line throws the error
    $theDay=$explodedDate[2]; //and also this line
    if((int)$theYear==(int)$thisYear && (int)$theMonth==(int)$thisMonth){
        if((int)$theDay==(int)$thisDay || (int)$thisDay==0){
            $debt+=$row['debt'];
            }
        }
    }
```

If you want to retry with commas for lines with an enrollment date formatted like yyyy,mm,dd you could do this.  It's not the most elegant solution, but it sounds like you have dirty data so may have to.

```
$thisMonth=$_POST['month']; //the value is today's date's month
$thisYear=$_POST['year']; //the value is today's date's year
$thisDay=$_POST['day']; //the value is today's date's day

$table=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `kids` WHERE `debt`!='0'") or die(mysql_error());
$debt=0;

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($table)){
    $explodedDate=explode('/',$row['enrollmentdate']);

    //try again with commas
    if ( count( $explodedDate ) == 0 ) {
        $explodedDate=explode(',',$row['enrollmentdate']);         
    }

    //skip the record if still no enrollment date
    if ( count( $explodedDate ) == 3 ) {

        $theYear=$explodedDate[0];
        $theMonth=$explodedDate[1]; //this line throws the error
        $theDay=$explodedDate[2]; //and also this line
        if((int)$theYear==(int)$thisYear && (int)$theMonth==(int)$thisMonth){
            if((int)$theDay==(int)$thisDay || (int)$thisDay==0){
                $debt+=$row['debt'];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is an interesting approach, but I fixed the database field (`enrollmentdate`) being empty bug and now it works as expected, thank you so much though +1

Comment: I read last of the comments on the initial question after posting the solution - sorry!  Glad you got it working.

Comment: okay I have to admit your way was brilliant, after trying to fix the bug (and failing and raising more bugs!) I tried your way of skipping the problem and it worked like a charm, thank you so much again ;)